# conditional format based on adjacent cell pivot table

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that compares two numbers adjacent to each other.  I want to create a conditional formatting rule that says if $C<>$D then turn background red, and ignore blanks.

[Sample of data]

[image]

For some reason the pivot table will not accept that formula.  I tried to use a relative cell "$C5" reference, however the pivot table uses the value of that cell for all formatting of every other cell. Please help with a formula I can use.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

[image]

For copying the formula is: `=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C16)),NOT(ISBLANK(D16))),C16<>D16)`